# What is a "PARTITIONED OUTER JOIN"?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, join, terminology

This just came up in a question on Reddit, and I'm wondering

- What is a `PARTITIONED OUTER JOIN` in Oracle? (definition)
- What does a simple example look like? (use)
- How would you write it in terms of PostgreSQL or Standard SQL that otherwise lacks `PARTITIONED OUTER JOIN`? (equivalence)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**{1} Partitioned Outer Join: Definition**

... "Such a join extends the conventional outer join syntax by applying the outer join to each logical partition defined in a query. Oracle logically partitions the rows in your query based on the expression you specify in the PARTITION BY clause. The result of a partitioned outer join is a UNION of the outer joins of each of the partitions in the logically partitioned table with the table on the other side of the join." ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/analysis.htm#DWHSG02013))

**{2} Simple Example**

"Data is normally stored in sparse form. That is, if no value exists for a given combination of dimension values, no row exists in the fact table. However, you may want to *view the data in dense form, with rows for all combination of dimension values displayed even when no fact data exist for them*."

... "For example, if a product did not sell during a particular time period, you may still want to see the product for that time period with zero sales value next to it." (quotes from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/analysis.htm#DWHSG02013))

Test tables and data (INSERTs)

```
-- Oracle 12c
create table sales (
  date_ date
, location_ varchar2( 16 )
, qty_ number
);

create table locations (
  name varchar2( 16 )
);

-- dates for locations are "gappy": 
-- none of the locations has entries for all 3 dates
-- ( date range: 2019-01-15 - 2019-01-17 )
insert into sales ( date_, location_, qty_ ) 
  values ( date '2019-01-17', 'London', 11 ) ;
insert into sales ( date_, location_, qty_ ) 
  values ( date '2019-01-15', 'London', 10 ) ;
insert into sales ( date_, location_, qty_ ) 
  values ( date '2019-01-16', 'Paris', 20 ) ;
insert into sales ( date_, location_, qty_ ) 
  values ( date '2019-01-17', 'Boston', 31 ) ;
insert into sales ( date_, location_, qty_ ) 
  values ( date '2019-01-16', 'Boston', 30 ) ;

-- locations
insert into locations ( name ) values ( 'London' );
insert into locations ( name ) values ( 'Paris' );
insert into locations ( name ) values ( 'Boston' );
```

Required output

```
date_       location_  qty_
2019-01-15  London     10
2019-01-15  Paris       0    -- not INSERTed!
2019-01-15  Boston      0    -- not INSERTed!
2019-01-16  London      0    -- not INSERTed!
2019-01-16  Paris      20
2019-01-16  Boston     30
2019-01-17  London     11
2019-01-17  Paris       0    -- not INSERTed!
2019-01-17  Boston     31
```

Query (partitioned outer join)

```
select S.date_, S.qty_, L.name
from sales S partition by ( date_ ) 
  right join locations L on S.location_ = L.name
;

-- result
DATE_      QTY_  NAME    
15-JAN-19  NULL  Boston  
15-JAN-19  10    London  
15-JAN-19  NULL  Paris   
16-JAN-19  30    Boston  
16-JAN-19  NULL  London  
16-JAN-19  20    Paris   
17-JAN-19  31    Boston  
17-JAN-19  11    London  
17-JAN-19  NULL  Paris
```

Query (version 2, same join)

```
-- same as above, using NVL(), column aliases, and ORDER BY ...
select S.date_, nvl( S.qty_, 0 ) as sold, L.name as location
from sales S partition by ( date_ ) 
  right join locations L on S.location_ = L.name
order by S.date_, L.name
;

DATE_           SOLD LOCATION        
--------- ---------- ----------------
15-JAN-19          0 Boston          
15-JAN-19         10 London          
15-JAN-19          0 Paris           
16-JAN-19         30 Boston          
16-JAN-19          0 London          
16-JAN-19         20 Paris           
17-JAN-19         31 Boston          
17-JAN-19         11 London          
17-JAN-19          0 Paris
```

[Dbfiddle here (Oracle 18c)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ce8a73774ec25eb7710cd788c0fcc355)

**{3} Equivalence**

The following query does roughly the same job as the PARTITION BY ( date_ ) outer join.  We are using a combination of a CROSS JOIN (inner SELECT) and LEFT OUTER JOIN.
(Conversion of NULLs to 0s omitted)

Oracle

```
select SL.*, S.qty_
from
(
  select *
  from (
    select unique date_ from sales
  ) , (
    select unique name from locations
  )
) SL left join (
  select date_, location_, qty_ from sales
) S on SL.name = S.location_ and SL.date_ = S.date_ 
order by SL.date_, SL.name
;

DATE_      NAME    QTY_  
15-JAN-19  Boston  NULL  
15-JAN-19  London  10    
15-JAN-19  Paris   NULL  
16-JAN-19  Boston  30    
16-JAN-19  London  NULL  
16-JAN-19  Paris   20    
17-JAN-19  Boston  31    
17-JAN-19  London  11    
17-JAN-19  Paris   NULL
```

PostgreSQL 10 ( [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=be37fdb556dc0a09a2108ef56114df75) )

```
-- DDL and INSERTs
create table sales (
  date_ date
, location_ varchar( 16 )
, qty_ number
);

create table locations (
  name varchar( 16 )
);

insert into sales ( date_, location_, qty_ ) values 
  ( '2019-01-17', 'London', 11 )
, ( '2019-01-15', 'London', 10 )
, ( '2019-01-16', 'Paris', 20 )
, ( '2019-01-17', 'Boston', 31 )
, ( '2019-01-16', 'Boston', 30 )

insert into locations ( name ) values 
( 'London' ), ( 'Paris' ), ( 'Boston' );
```

Query (Postgres)

```
-- SL: all date_ <-> location combinations
-- S: all location_ and qty_ values of table sales
select SL.*, S.qty_
from
(
  select *
  from (
    select distinct date_ from sales
  ) S_ cross join (
    select distinct name from locations
  ) L_
) SL left join (
  select date_, location_, qty_ from sales
) S on SL.name = S.location_ and SL.date_ = S.date_ 
order by SL.date_, SL.name
;

date_        name    qty_
2019-01-15   Boston  
2019-01-15   London  10
2019-01-15   Paris    
2019-01-16   Boston  30
2019-01-16   London    
2019-01-16   Paris   20
2019-01-17   Boston  31
2019-01-17   London  11
2019-01-17   Paris
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometime a better execution plan can be obtained by this equivalence :

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT S.date_, S.qty_, L.name
FROM   sales S  
       INNER JOIN locations L 
          ON S.location_ = L.name
)
SELECT * 
FROM   T
UNION  ALL
SELECT DISTINCT S.date_, NULL, L.name
FROM   sales S  
       CROSS JOIN locations L
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                  FROM   T 
                  WHERE  T.date_ = S.date_ 
                         AND L.name = T.name)
ORDER  BY date_, name
```

Also :

```
WITH 
T AS (SELECT DISTINCT date_, X.location_ 
      FROM   sales 
             CROSS JOIN (SELECT location_ 
                         FROM   sales) AS X)
SELECT T.date_, T.location_, S.qty_ 
FROM   T
       LEFT OUTER JOIN sales AS S
          ON T.date_ = S.date_ AND T.location_ = S.location_
          LEFT OUTER JOIN locations AS L
             ON S.location_ = L.name;
```